# Multiple netlify static sites served under a single cloudfront domain path

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, amazon-cloudfront, python-sphinx, netlify

I have multiple netlify static sites that I want to serve in their entirety under a path of a cloudfront domain.  However, resources that don't reside at the root of the netlify app are not being served (raise a 404)

i.e.

**https://netlify1-abcd123.netlify.app/**

- /
- /page1

  - /page1/subpage1
- /page2
- /images/logo.png
- /stylesheets/styles.css

**https://netlify2-defg456.netlify.app/**

- /
- /netlify2-page1

  - /netlify2-page1/subpage1
- /netlify2-page2
- /netlify2-images/logo.png
- /netlify2-stylesheets/styles.css

and I want these to be served under `www.mydomain.com/netflify1` and `www.mydomain.com/netlify2`.  The root of `www.mydomain.com` is currently served via an S3 static site.

I have configured rewrite rules in netlify.toml for each site (changing as appropriate to `netlify2`) as below:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/netlify1/*"
  to = "https://netlify1-abcd123.netlify.app/:splat"
  status = 200
  force = true
```

...and then added an Origin to Cloudfront which has the Origin Domain Name of `https://netlify1-abcd123.netlify.app/` - all other Origin settings are the defaults.

I've then configured a Behaviour with a Path Pattern `netlify1` that points to the `netlify1` origin.  Note that I cannot use the `Default` behaviour as the main index of `www.mydomain.com` is served via a static site hosted on S3.

This all works perfectly fine when serving the root `/` of my netlify app.  I can navigate to `www.mydomain.com/netlify1` and see the home page of my netlify app.  However,  anything that is not on the `/` of netlify doesn't get served.

I can see from the developer tools that a request is being made to `www.mydomain.com/images/logo.png` and `www.mydomain.com/stylesheets/styles.css` when trying to load the images and the styles.  This returns a 404 because (I presume) they are not getting picked up by any Cloudfront Behaviour or Netlify rewrite rules.

So my question is.  How can I make images, stylesheets and any page not on the root of the netlify apps work correctly?  I can make it work by manually added every single potential path as a Behaviour on Cloudfront (i.e. configure a Behaviour with a Path Pattern of `/images/*` to point to the `netlify1` Origin) - but that doesn't seem scalable or even correct.

I don't know whether I need to somehow rewrite all my URLs on the netlify app during building so that they become `/netlify1/images` and `/netlify/page1` rather than `/images` and `/page1` (the netlify apps are docs built with Sphinx docs), or whether this is something that needs to be handled via a Rewrite Rule in Lambda@Edge.  I'm completely stumped.